# UICollectionViewCell will not find Custom Cell to load image

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView with a custom Cell containing one image and one label.  I load the data via XML, but I am using a multithread to bind the data of the image in the cells.  I am not setting the image to load on the cellForItemAtIndexPath, but I am loading the description from here.

My problem is that the images do not load initially.  When I scroll, it does load because I have a method in scrollView:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate { 
if (!decelerate)
{
    [self loadImagesForOnscreenCells];
}}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{      
    [self loadImagesForOnscreenCells];   
}
```

I use the following to load the description:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; { 
Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.label.text = xmlPhotosVideosRecordPointer.title;
```

This is the loadImagesForOnscreenCells:

```
- (void)loadImagesForOnscreenCells
{
if ([xmlPhotosVideosRecords count] > 0)
{
    NSArray *visiblePaths = [newsTable indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
    {            
        xmlPhotosVideosRecord *xmlPhotosVideosRecordPointer = [self.xmlPhotosVideosRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if (!xmlPhotosVideosRecordPointer.thumbImage)
        {
            [self startIconDownload:xmlPhotosVideosRecordPointer forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }  
}
}
```

That being said, is there a way to delegate when the UICollectionView didLoad?  This way, I could use
    [self loadImagesForOnscreenCells]; to refresh the images on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and it works! Use:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```